# Product of arrays (einsum) of 3D arrays containing only -1 or +1

Tags: algorithm, numpy, matrix-multiplication, numpy-einsum

Let X be an array of shape (M, k, g) and Q be an array of shape (m, k, g), where m, M, k, and g can be "very large". Suppose the entries of X and Y are either -1 or plus +1. I'm interested in the array Z of shape (m, M, k) defined by Z[a,b,i] = Q[a,i] @ X[b,i]. It is clear that this can be accomplished in Numpy (or Jax, for GPU exploitation) like so

```
Z = einsum("mkg,Mkg->mMk", Q, X)
```

**Question.** Can Z be computed more efficiently by using the information that the entries of X and Y are -1 or +1 ?

Comment: What dtype are you using atm?

Comment: @Learningisamess Thanks for the question (which is actually a tip). I should definitely be using something like int8. Is this what you meant.

Comment: Yeah that's where I was heading, not sure it would speed it up but I would benchmark casting to small int type (such as int8) vs not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, casting to int8 seems to give a speed up. If you are able and willing to use torch, I see a speedup when using their einsum (cannot elaborate on which optimizations they are using), seems slower if casting to their int8 type though:

[image]

---

Comment: Thanks. I can reproduce you experiment. So Pytorch for the win! With GPU this would produce even bigger gains. It is indeed strange that pytorch int8 is slower than floatxy. Also, it turns out that (JAX) is slower than barebones numpy...

Comment: I am glad if this helped. Thanks for reporting on the GPU performance.

Comment: Sure, see my post below. Thanks again!

Comment: I just had a look, ~300x speedup from CPU to GPU with torch, that is sweet!!

Answer (score 0):

Here are some more benchmarks on GPU (T4) to complement the accepted answer. I compared Numpy vs JAX vs PyTorch

CPU

[image]

GPU

[image]

The conclusion (based on this tiny experiment) is:

- Only Numpy knows how to take full advantage int8. The others are probably doing some weird casting under the hood.
- GPU helps JAX.
- PyTorch is a beast on GPU.